# How to assign a 1d tensor to a 2d tensor using a mask matrix in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

1st: mask (11 true)

2nd: array (11 element)

3nd: zero_tensor (same shape as mask tensor): i want the position can be assigned corresponding element in array (position that was true in mask)

In torch, we can use `zero_tensor[mask] = array`, but how to do in tensorflow?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

x = tf.zeros((5, 3), dtype=tf.int32)
new_values = tf.constant([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5], dtype=tf.int32)
mask = tf.constant([[True, True, True],
                    [True, True, True],
                    [True, False, False],
                    [True, True, False],
                    [True, True, False]])
print(x)
new_x = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(x, tf.where(mask), new_values)
print(new_x)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]], shape=(5, 3), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 0 0]
 [4 4 0]
 [5 5 0]], shape=(5, 3), dtype=int32)
```